# FB.Canvas.setAutoResize just keeps going

Tags: javascript, facebook

I added

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
```

to my page so that my FB application can auto size. However my page doesn't stop growing. It just keeps getting longer. 
What am I doing wrong?

---

Maybe it was my styling. Things are working with these lines commented out.

body {
        padding: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

```
html, body, #wrapper {
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

body > #wrapper {
    /*height: auto;*/
    /*min-height: 99.65%;*/
    margin-top: -105px;
}
```

I'll close this question if this works.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: I've got `<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

    };

</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the reason my page kept getting longer was because I had set height to 100% and then height to auto as seen above. Once I removed these lines the page resized normally.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
removing height 100% may resolve it...

But I found the core of the problem was a margin-top on a div inside of my wrapper.  Which seemed to make Facebook mis-calculate the height of the doc and make it keep increasing in size.